# C#: ILogger vs static Log instance

Tags: c#, logging, architecture

This is more an architectural question:
Do you use ILogger (and pass it in the constructor via DI) or do you  prefer a static class Log?

We use ILogger a lot but it really seems to clatter the code especially when it is passed via constructor. If not passed via constructor and just every time created, then I really do not see a benefit if using the interface.

So how do you handle this? I am especially interested in the arguments behind it - not just saying "static" or "interface".

Thx

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using a static instance of anything is a bad idea for different reasons, depending on your use case.
-   They are difficult to mock in a unit test so your logger is always writing logs even when they are not needed.
-   Lack of mocking also means you cannot write tests to ensure an error log is written in appropriate situations.
-   They cannot be replaced at runtime to allow injection of different loggers.  This can be important if you are releasing a library for others to use.  I define a standard logger interface and log everything to that, then allow clients to inject their own logger as long as it implements my interface.
-   If you use the default static Log implementation provided by the vendor, you are locked into their interface meaning you cannot hide or change the surface area of the logger.  Changing loggers becomes a MUCH bigger effort if the syntax of the new logger changes.

So that leaves you with some kind of injection.  Personally I prefer having all dependencies in the constructor, even if it becomes verbose, because it’s easy to see all dependencies a particular class has. If you are trying to avoid a big constructor you can look into Property Injection.  This requires an attribute on a property of the class, but still gives you all the advantages of injecting the dependencies.  If you put the injected property on a base class it will be available for all children automatically.

BTW, I’m not a fan of the Ambient Context described above because it’s basically a single purpose DI container, and you must have a concrete reference to multiple ambient service containers.  If the easy access of this pattern appeals to you, look into Service Location which is the same idea but more flexible.

Comment: Thanks. After discussing this with a senior colleague, we think we have to stick to the constructor injection.

Comment: they're not difficult to mock, just replace global/static instance of ILogger in your tests

Comment: +1 @Brad Irby, would you have an example to provide that uses DI on protperties using an attribute? Would be very much appreciated!

Comment: I use Unity and prefer constructor injection, so I don't have any current examples handy.  However there is an example here.  https://www.tutorialsteacher.com/ioc/property-injection-using-unity-container  It looks dated (still uses Unity 3 instead of the current 5) but the idea is the same.  If you like AutoFac then try here: https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/register/prop-method-injection.html  .  Basically just google your favorite DI container with "property injection" and you'll find examples.

Comment: This is the old school, extremist, height of DI mania approach. 1. You can have a static `Logger` class and do setup on it, so it acts differently in different contexts (production, testing, switching during runtime, ...). 2. It downplays the boilerplate this approach causes (aka 'pollution' but I don't like propaganda terms like that), when you have multiple cross-cutting things getting injected all the time. 3. The other approaches that aren't constructor injection require inheritance, which can be limiting. In summary: It's more about taste than truth - both approaches can be done right.

Answer (score 4):

If `ILogger` is really a cross-cutting concern, which is used everywhere and thus just causes to pollute every instance with a new constructor parameter, then what you need is to you use a special way of dependency injection called [`AmbientContext`](https://nathanjohnstone.wordpress.com/2016/03/27/ambient-context/).

Basically it provides you a singleton `Context` property, which can be accessed from anywhere in the business scope and contains the "global" dependencies such as logging, time service, etc., whatever you need.

But please note that it doesn't mean you can throw out your `ILogger` and use a static `Log` class with a hardcoded implementation. Ambient context is also a way of dependency injection so its dependencies should be resolved.

Comment: you can  use static `ILogger` and still be able to mock it if you care that much about tests